# Python Pandas create running 'id' based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to create a unique 'ID' field for my Pandas rows based on certain conditions related to the previous rows.

Below you will see a sample of my data:

```
  current_driver customer_id    pu_actual_dt      service
0        167       1214      2018-06-28 13:24:00    DED
1        167       1214      2018-06-28 13:25:00    DED
2        167       1214      2018-06-28 14:43:00    DED
3        243       1214      2018-06-28 19:41:00    DED
4        243       1214      2018-06-28 19:41:00    DED
5        250       1214      2018-06-28 17:19:00    DED
6        250       1214      2018-06-28 18:00:00    DED
7        250       1214      2018-06-28 18:18:00    DED
8        259       1214      2018-06-28 19:40:00    DED
9        259       1214      2018-06-28 19:40:00    DED
10       259       1214      2018-06-28 20:14:00    DED
11       260       1214      2018-06-28 17:39:00    DED
12       260       1214      2018-06-28 17:39:00    DED
13       260       1214      2018-06-28 17:39:00    DED
14       260       1214      2018-06-28 17:39:00    DED
15       263       1214      2018-06-28 18:34:00    DED
16       263       1214      2018-06-28 18:43:00    DED
17       263       1214      2018-06-28 18:43:00    DED
```

What I need to do is create another column with the following logic: If the current_driver is the same as the current_driver of the previous row AND the customer_id is the same as the customer_id of the previous row AND the pu_actual_dt is within a half-hour of the previous row, then it should all have the same ID. So it would start at "1" for the first two rows, but since the third row the pu_actual_dt is more than a half-hour later, it would have the ID of "2". Then the fourth row has a different driver, so that would have the ID of "3", along with row # 5 since it has the same driver / customer_id / pu_actual_dt as row #4.

Before I accounted for minor differences in the pu_actual_dt (see the first two rows), I was able to solve it by concatenating the fields and starting a new ID each time the row didn't match the previous concatenation. So for instance, I used this to create the ID before:

```
df = df.assign(id=(df['route_concate']).astype('category').cat.codes)
```

However, that concatenation logic doesn't work when I have minor differences in the pu_actual_dt.

So I tried to account for the minor time changes by doing this:

```
df['id'] = np.where((df['current_driver'] == df['current_driver'].shift(1) ) 
& (df['customer_id'] == df['customer_id'].shift(1)) 
& (df['pu_actual_dt'] < df['pu_actual_dt'].shift(1) + pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)) 
& (df['pu_actual_dt'] > df['pu_actual_dt'].shift(1) - pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)) 
& (df['service'] == 'DED'), df['id'].shift(1), df['id'].shift(1) + 1)
```

What I am trying to do here is say for each row, if the current_driver = current_driver in above row and customer_id = customer_id in above row, pu_actual_dt is within 30 minutes before or after the pu_actual_dt in previous row, and service = 'DED', then use the ID of the previous row. If not, then add 1 to the ID of the previous row.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it is returning some very unpredictable results. At one point it goes down from ID 75 to 34 and then back to 36?

What is a better solution to my problem? (Also one where the ID will start at "1"). Thanks for your help as always!

Comment: Please replace your screenshot with a textual representation of your data!

Comment: @Nils There, I fixed it. Column titles don't necessarily match up with the columns but close enough.

Comment: Where my code seems to fail is where I am adding the ID from the previous column. I am not entirely sure why my shift attempt is not working, but it is giving me results I can't make sense of. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `np.where` is a good idea with a small difference: assign `1` if the condition is not met and `None` if met such as:

```
df['id'] = np.where((df['current_driver'] == df['current_driver'].shift(1) ) 
& (df['customer_id'] == df['customer_id'].shift(1)) 
& (df['pu_actual_dt'] < df['pu_actual_dt'].shift(1) + pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)) 
& (df['pu_actual_dt'] > df['pu_actual_dt'].shift(1) - pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)) 
& (df['service'] == 'DED'), None, 1) # NOTE the None and 1 here are explain above
```

Now you have `1` each row you want to increment the value in `id`, so a use of [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), `ffill` and `astype` (to ge integer not float) such as:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].cumsum().ffill().astype(int)
```

gives with your example

```
    current_driver  customer_id        pu_actual_dt service  id
0              167         1214 2018-06-28 13:24:00     DED   1
1              167         1214 2018-06-28 13:25:00     DED   1
2              167         1214 2018-06-28 14:43:00     DED   2
3              243         1214 2018-06-28 19:41:00     DED   3
4              243         1214 2018-06-28 19:41:00     DED   3
5              250         1214 2018-06-28 17:19:00     DED   4
6              250         1214 2018-06-28 18:00:00     DED   5
7              250         1214 2018-06-28 18:18:00     DED   5
8              259         1214 2018-06-28 19:40:00     DED   6
9              259         1214 2018-06-28 19:40:00     DED   6
10             259         1214 2018-06-28 20:14:00     DED   7
11             260         1214 2018-06-28 17:39:00     DED   8
12             260         1214 2018-06-28 17:39:00     DED   8
13             260         1214 2018-06-28 17:39:00     DED   8
14             260         1214 2018-06-28 17:39:00     DED   8
15             263         1214 2018-06-28 18:34:00     DED   9
16             263         1214 2018-06-28 18:43:00     DED   9
17             263         1214 2018-06-28 18:43:00     DED   9
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me so much frustration and I didn't want to go into the weekend with this problem hanging over my head! :)

Comment: @Emac yeah, free head for week-end ^^ btw, I tried your code giving you the error. I think the problem is when you use `df['id'].shift(1)` or `df['id'].shift(1)+1` to assign a new value, it was `df['id']` before you start to reincrement the value, not with the new value you just incremented, so it's why you did not have consistent increment (hope it's clear...)